# Use sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner in browser without Fiori client

Tags: sapui5

I am unsing the sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner in my application.
In my view I have:

```
<Button icon="sap-icon://bar-code" press="scanBarcode"/>
<Label id="label" text="Null"/>
```

scanBarcode looks like this:

```
scanBarcode: function(oEvent) {
    sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner.scan(
        var that = this;
        function (mResult) {
             if (!mResult.cancelled) {
                 var code = mResult.text;
                 that.byId("label").setText(code);
             }
        },
        function (Error) {
            if (Error !== undefined) {
                MessageBox.error(Error.message);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

My problem is that I do not want to use the Fiori client to access the application.
Therefore, it should be possible to use the barcode scanner in a browser using the device's camera.

Is it possible to do that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to use the barcode scanner in a browser.

The sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner is declared under the namespace sap.ndc. Here the "ndc" stands for Native Device Capabilities. Those APIs will use the cordova plugins to invoke the native devices functions, for example the Camera. The sap.ndc.BarcodeScanner will check the availability of cordova plugins. If the app is opened via browser, then BarcodeScanner will simply open a dialog and ask end user to manually enter the barcode. If the app is opened via a cordova application or SAP Fiori Client (which is built on top of cordova), then it will invoke device camera.